# identify unique entry list of a list

Tags: r

```
Column1A<-Dat$col1
Column1B<-Dat2$col2
```

Both columns, column1A and column1B consist of mixed values, such as ABC1, 234,etc. Besides, each column can have duplicate entries. For instance,

```
Column1A
ABC1   ABC2   1234  ABC1

Column1B
ABC2   ABC3   1234
```

Is there a way to get the unique entry list for each column. If the unique entry list are difference for two columns, how to find the differences?

Answer (score 1):

`unique` should work in getting unique values for a list.

For searching the different terms in two unique lists, you can just simply go through one of the list, and for each element of that list, check if that is in the other list.

A simple while loop should work, and you stop at the point when you cannot find an element from list 1 in list 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique` to find the unique values:

```
unique(Column1A)

unique(Column1B)
```

Answer (score 0):

since your data is already in a data.frame or a list, no need to first copy them out. Just use `apply`:

```
apply(Dat, 2, unique)
```